# How to add 'libs' folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, libs

I need help in creating the 'libs' folder in Android Studio for my project (It is not auto-generated in my project).

When I want to create a folder, it gives me lots of options, like AIDL, Assets, JNI, Java, Java Resources, Renderscripts, and 'res' folders. I chose **Res** and added a libs folder but it didn't show up on my file structure on the left.

Can anyone help me?

I wanted to add a JAR file but I can't find libs to put in.

Comment: just create it from a file explorer, it should work!

Comment: Can you teach me in details? I have no idea where to create in. 
Here is my dir : C:\Users\Juicy\Desktop\Utranslator\app\src\main\res

Is it here?

Comment: It still does not show in my Android Project on my left hand side in Android Studio. I cant use my jar

Comment: then create the folder **libs** into **c:/users/juicy/desktop/Utranslator/app/** ... It should show up, I think there's an icon to refresh the tree. Also, copy the library right away into the created dir with the file explorer, exit and re-run Android Studio

Comment: Sorry to say that its still not working. The libs file is like invisible in Android Studio but it exists in File Explorer

Comment: sorry to hear that, unfortunately I cant be of much help because I dont have android studio installed at the moment, however there should be a refresh button somewhere! wish you luck!

Comment: Could you accept one of reply as "answer".

Answer (score 548, accepted):

The solution for me was very simple (after 10 hours of searching).
Above where your folders are there is a combobox that says "android"
click it and choose "Project".

[image]

Comment: yeah they did hide that folder. If the font for the library names are in orange does it have any meaning? Looking to end this torture...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can I get an explanation as to why it doesn't show up in the Android heading?

Comment: wow.. and here I was wondering why there were so many ways to view my project. This combobox is just a combo of stupidity and needlessness in my opinion. How Eclipse did it before worked, just show us everything! Props for giving us the solution!

Comment: Thanks. Solved the issue. It's hilarious, that this view isn't the standard view in a Flutter project when you just created - a Flutter project. Maybe, there is a bit of work for the responsible developers here to be done...?

Answer (score 217):

*Click the left side dropdown menu*  "android" and choose **"project"** *to see libs folders*

[image]

*after choosing project you will see the libs directory

Answer (score 14):

libs and Assets folder in Android Studio:

Create libs folder inside app folder and Asset folder inside main in the project directory by exploring project directory.

Now come back to Android Studio and switch the combo box from Android to Project. enjoy...

Answer (score 8):

also, to get the right arrow, right click and "Add as Library".[image]

Comment: Add as Library is not available with the new versions.

Comment: Its available in electric eil 

Answer (score 5):

Another strange thing. You wont see the libs folder in Android Studio, unless you have at least 1 file in the folder. So, I had to go to the libs folder using File Explorer, and then place the jar file there. Then, it showed up in Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

also you should click right button on mouse at your projectname and choose "open module settings" or press F4 button. Then on "dependencies" tab add your lib.jar to declare needed lib

Answer (score 3):

You can create lib folder inside app you press right click and select directory you named as **libs** its will be worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Android Studio, and click **File** > **Project Structure**.
2. Redirect to **Project Settings** > **Module**.
3. Select **yourProjectName_android** and remove it by clicking (-) minus sign shown on above.
4. Now click on **yourProjectName** and click on + Add
   Content Root and just provide the path of your project.
5. Just Apply and Ok.
6. Restart your android studio.