# Trying to add files to my External Libraries folder in Android Studio 1.4 Beta 2 to no avail.

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, android-youtube-api

Trying to follow this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

I found this thread got me to see my external libraries directory

[Have no libs directory in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956827/have-no-libs-directory-in-android-studio)

but I can't add the jar file for the Youtube API to it - what am I doing wrong? It won't let me drag it in or copy and paste it.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by simply updating to latest.