# Where to put apache http legacy jar? App / Libs folder disappeared in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-httpclient-4.x, libs

I need to be able to add `.jars` to my project to solve the problem of the apache `http package`  not being available anymore. Like here:

[HttpClient won't import in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio)

Problem is that the `Libs` as well as App folder totally disappeared from my project overview. And manually adding an `app/libs` folder is not working either

Neither is any possible solution as mentioned here.
[Have no libs directory in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956827/have-no-libs-directory-in-android-studio)

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why your app/libs folders disappeared? Have you found it in *Windows Explorer* or by choosing `Project` in *Android Studio* as the following screenshot?

[image: BNK's screenshot]

Comment: I went to project just as you show in your screenshot. No libs folder there. Added one manually and copied my jar into it, but that didn't work for me yet.

Comment: Yes. Creating a new project creates a libs folder within the app folder... strange... have to get back to and try to solve this issue in a while due to different project priorities atm. Tnx for the effort.

Comment: Check folder permissions if writable